# Retreive the Content location of a picture stored in games persisteant data path

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am having a little issue when trying to pass an image uri to androids gallery.

The code for openign the image in the gallery is working as it comes up with a selection box to choose the application to open the uri.

The uri that I am using is `content://Android/data/com.littleminimonsters.match/files/LMM_Ghost_20181130.png`

Is that the correct way to format a content uri? the file is stored in that location but on the SDCard (`Android/data/com....`)

I've tried just using the full path too with no luck (`content://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com...`)

Any ideas on what the content uri should be?

Comment: The tile of your question  is different from  what the body is saying. Title says that the data is at persistent data path. Body is saying the data is at the androids gallery loccaation. These are different. Which one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Programmer but the image itself is in the persistant data path (com.littleminimonsters.com). What I am trying to do is generate a correct UriObject to pass over to the gallery application so it an be viewed in the native gallery application